# How can I get passed this zipHMMlib build error on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, c++, make, build, cmake

I've installed the latest Ubuntu Server on an Oracle VirtualBox 64-bit machine instance, with host machine Windows 10 and 64-bit OS.

I installed a "slim" desktop environment using a random googled-for article on that.  Everything works fine, including internet connectivity and in fact I'm making this post in Firefox from the Ubuntu instance.

Also, another prequisite is the famous Linear Algebra library called ATLAS, and here are the instructions I used to install it:
https://gist.github.com/sangheestyle/ca8ef7796aefadad8773

Some googling around to install further prerequisites and so on, was required.  I think there might be an easier install method, but I could be confusing it with something else I did.  Anyway, these instructions are fairly simple and like I say below, building zipHMMlib (what I'm having trouble on) seems to find ATLAS okay, or its make error does not seem to be related to my ATLAS install.

---

My problem is going through the instructions on:

https://github.com/mailund/ziphmm

It's really neat, an HMM library that reduces computation time by noting repeated sequences of inputs.  In some cases learning an HMM model took 9 hours on standard implementations and only 8 minutes using this library, or so the research paper reports.

Anyhow, I've tried both the release code here:

https://birc.au.dk/software/ziphmm/

And the git code.  I download or git the repository to copy the source code to my server, use `cd` to get into the directory downloaded (after unzipping if necessary) and run the instructions found on the above github link.

To be exact, they are:

```
$ cd <path to library>/zipHMM-1.0.1/
zipHMM-1.0.1 $ cmake .
zipHMM-1.0.1 $ make
zipHMM-1.0.1 $ bin/calibrate
zipHMM-1.0.1 $ make test
zipHMM-1.0.1 $ make install
```

Now, after installing the Python Dev libraries using `apt-get install`, the `cmake .` command goes through cleanly.

But when I run `make` it starts building for a while, lots of `.o` files, a great sign!  And then it fail with (in total - I included everything, so see the bottom lines below):

```
oot@mechanikos-industries-ubuntu-server:/home/enjoysmath/zipHMM-1.0.1# make
[ 20%] Built target zipHMM
[ 21%] Building CXX object zipHMM/CMakeFiles/pyZipHMM.dir/pyZipHMM.cpp.o
[ 21%] Building CXX object zipHMM/CMakeFiles/pyZipHMM.dir/forwarder.cpp.o
[ 22%] Building CXX object zipHMM/CMakeFiles/pyZipHMM.dir/simple_stop_forwarder.cpp.o
[ 23%] Building CXX object zipHMM/CMakeFiles/pyZipHMM.dir/matrix.cpp.o
[ 24%] Building CXX object zipHMM/CMakeFiles/pyZipHMM.dir/seq_io.cpp.o
[ 24%] Building CXX object zipHMM/CMakeFiles/pyZipHMM.dir/hmm_io.cpp.o
[ 25%] Building CXX object zipHMM/CMakeFiles/pyZipHMM.dir/io_utils.cpp.o
[ 26%] Building CXX object zipHMM/CMakeFiles/pyZipHMM.dir/prob_spaces.cpp.o
[ 26%] Building CXX object zipHMM/CMakeFiles/pyZipHMM.dir/hmm_utils.cpp.o
[ 27%] Building CXX object zipHMM/CMakeFiles/pyZipHMM.dir/PThreadProcessingDevice.cpp.o
[ 28%] Building CXX object zipHMM/CMakeFiles/pyZipHMM.dir/performance_description.cpp.o
[ 28%] Building CXX object zipHMM/CMakeFiles/pyZipHMM.dir/Stage1JobControl.cpp.o
[ 29%] Building CXX object zipHMM/CMakeFiles/pyZipHMM.dir/posterior_decoding.cpp.o
[ 30%] Building CXX object zipHMM/CMakeFiles/pyZipHMM.dir/viterbi.cpp.o
[ 31%] Building CXX object zipHMM/CMakeFiles/pyZipHMM.dir/debug.cpp.o
[ 31%] Linking CXX shared library libpyZipHMM.so
[ 31%] Built target pyZipHMM
[ 32%] Linking CXX executable ../bin/calibrate
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/calibrate.dir/PThreadProcessingDevice.cpp.o: in function `zipHMM::PThreadProcessingDevice::computeSymbol2ScaleAndSymbol2Matrix(zipHMM::Stage1JobControl&)':
/home/enjoysmath/zipHMM-1.0.1/zipHMM/PThreadProcessingDevice.cpp:83: undefined reference to `pthread_create'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/calibrate.dir/PThreadProcessingDevice.cpp.o: in function `zipHMM::PThreadProcessingDevice::likelihoodVector(zipHMM::Stage2JobControl&)':
/home/enjoysmath/zipHMM-1.0.1/zipHMM/PThreadProcessingDevice.cpp:183: undefined reference to `pthread_create'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/calibrate.dir/PThreadProcessingDevice.cpp.o: in function `zipHMM::PThreadProcessingDevice::likelihoodMatrix(zipHMM::Stage2JobControl&)':
/home/enjoysmath/zipHMM-1.0.1/zipHMM/PThreadProcessingDevice.cpp:187: undefined reference to `pthread_create'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/calibrate.dir/PThreadProcessingDevice.cpp.o: in function `zipHMM::PThreadProcessingDevice::join()':
/home/enjoysmath/zipHMM-1.0.1/zipHMM/PThreadProcessingDevice.cpp:466: undefined reference to `pthread_join'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [zipHMM/CMakeFiles/calibrate.dir/build.make:268: bin/calibrate] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:217: zipHMM/CMakeFiles/calibrate.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:182: all] Error 2
```

So googling around people say when that happens you need `CFLAGS` or `CXX_FLAGS` to include `-lpthread`.  I manually verified as best I could that `CXX_FLAGS` sent to the make instruction for those above-failed .o files is correct.  I edited `flags.make` burried in some directory (found by grepping around) and saw that `-lpthread` was there.  I also outputted the CMake build flags with:

```
root@mechanikos-industries-ubuntu-server:/home/enjoysmath/zipHMM-1.0.1# cmake -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON .
-- CXX_FLAGS:  -Wall -Wconversion -O3 -g -lpthread
-- PYTHON_SITE_PACKAGES: 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/enjoysmath/zipHMM-1.0.1
```

So apparently it's set up correctly to include pthread support.  So how can I find out more information about why those lines are failing to make properly?  There is absolutely zero guidance on the web for this particular library because I guess no one's really used it much except for the original creators.  I can try posting an issue there on the github page, but I like I said the latest post was 5 years ago, so...  I think here is a better spot and I think this is pretty easy to fix to someone who's had similar build issues.

So please help.  I really want to use this optimal HMM library.

If you can help me get it to work, I can then fork their repository and keep a working copy of it and help others, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the error output I was getting I plugged that into the following command:

```
make --just-print | grep /PThreadProcessingDevice.cpp.o
```

---

That outputs the following:

```
/home/enjoysmath/zipHMM-1.0.1# make --just-print | grep /PThreadProcessingDevice.cpp.o
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_echo_color --switch= --green --progress-dir=/home/enjoysmath/zipHMM-1.0.1/CMakeFiles --progress-num= "Building CXX object zipHMM/CMakeFiles/build_forwarder.dir/PThreadProcessingDevice.cpp.o"
cd /home/enjoysmath/zipHMM-1.0.1/zipHMM && /usr/bin/c++  -I/home/enjoysmath/zipHMM-1.0.1 -I/com/extra/ATLAS/3.9.84/i`enter code here`nclude -I/usr/include/python3.9 -Wall -Wconversion -O3 -g -lpthread -o CMakeFiles/build_forwarder.dir/PThreadProcessingDevice.cpp.o -c /home/enjoysmath/zipHMM-1.0.1/zipHMM/PThreadProcessingDevice.cpp
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_echo_color --switch= --green --progress-dir=/home/enjoysmath/zipHMM-1.0.1/CMakeFiles --progress-num= "Building CXX object zipHMM/CMakeFiles/forward.dir/PThreadProcessingDevice.cpp.o"
cd /home/enjoysmath/zipHMM-1.0.1/zipHMM && /usr/bin/c++  -I/home/enjoysmath/zipHMM-1.0.1 -I/com/extra/ATLAS/3.9.84/include -I/usr/include/python3.9 -Wall -Wconversion -O3 -g -lpthread -o CMakeFiles/forward.dir/PThreadProcessingDevice.cpp.o -c /home/enjoysmath/zipHMM-1.0.1/zipHMM/PThreadProcessingDevice.cpp
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_echo_color --switch= --green --progress-dir=/home/enjoysmath/zipHMM-1.0.1/CMakeFiles --progress-num= "Building CXX object zipHMM/CMakeFiles/cpp_example.dir/PThreadProcessingDevice.cpp.o"
cd /home/enjoysmath/zipHMM-1.0.1/zipHMM && /usr/bin/c++  -I/home/enjoysmath/zipHMM-1.0.1 -I/com/extra/ATLAS/3.9.84/include -I/usr/include/python3.9 -Wall -Wconversion -O3 -g -lpthread -o CMakeFiles/cpp_example.dir/PThreadProcessingDevice.cpp.o -c /home/enjoysmath/zipHMM-1.0.1/zipHMM/PThreadProcessingDevice.cpp
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_echo_color --switch= --green --progress-dir=/home/enjoysmath/zipHMM-1.0.1/CMakeFiles --progress-num=68 "Building CXX object zipHMM/CMakeFiles/test_device_io.dir/PThreadProcessingDevice.cpp.o"
cd /home/enjoysmath/zipHMM-1.0.1/zipHMM && /usr/bin/c++  -I/home/enjoysmath/zipHMM-1.0.1 -I/com/extra/ATLAS/3.9.84/include -I/usr/include/python3.9 -Wall -Wconversion -O3 -g -lpthread -o CMakeFiles/test_device_io.dir/PThreadProcessingDevice.cpp.o -c /home/enjoysmath/zipHMM-1.0.1/zipHMM/PThreadProcessingDevice.cpp
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_echo_color --switch= --green --progress-dir=/home/enjoysmath/zipHMM-1.0.1/CMakeFiles --progress-num=78 "Building CXX object zipHMM/CMakeFiles/test_forwarder.dir/PThreadProcessingDevice.cpp.o"
cd /home/enjoysmath/zipHMM-1.0.1/zipHMM && /usr/bin/c++  -I/home/enjoysmath/zipHMM-1.0.1 -I/com/extra/ATLAS/3.9.84/include -I/usr/include/python3.9 -Wall -Wconversion -O3 -g -lpthread -o CMakeFiles/test_forwarder.dir/PThreadProcessingDevice.cpp.o -c /home/enjoysmath/zipHMM-1.0.1/zipHMM/PThreadProcessingDevice.cpp
root@mechanikos-industries-ubuntu-server:/home/enjoysmath/zipHMM-1.0.1#
```

As you can see, each compilation instrution, `-lpthread` is passed in, but I edited `flags.make` prior to this to be the following:

```
# compile CXX with /usr/bin/c++
CXX_DEFINES =

CXX_INCLUDES = -I/home/enjoysmath/zipHMM-1.0.1 -I/com/extra/ATLAS/3.9.84/include -I/usr/include/python3.9

CXX_FLAGS =  -Wall -Wconversion -O3 -g -pthread
```

Note the `-pthread`  instead of `-lpthread`.  That's what I changed, but the make command is using a prior setting somehow.  But at least I got what its sending and using `-pthread` instead is worth a try, so I'll try to figure out now or the new question is: where is make taking its flags from?

---

Got it to magically build by replacing all occurences of `lpthread` with `pthread` after running `cmake .`:

```
grep -rl lpthread ./ | xargs sed -i 's/lpthread/pthread/g'
```

I'm still not sure where `cmake` is determining that it should send in `lpthread`.

The successful build output should look like this on standard slim desktop of Ubuntu server:

[image: Virtual Box instance screenshot, showing successful build of zipHMMLib]

---

I've made a fork of the repository here:

https://github.com/enjoysmath/ziphmm

With the above correction for Ubuntu put into the readme markdown.

I will try to maintain the library, so if you have any issues, please post in the Issues forum linked to on that github page.